# My app got submitted to the Apptivate.ms contest multiple times because of an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, apptivate.ms

My app got submitted to Apptivate three times within about five minutes because I got the Stack Overflow "an error has occurred on our end" page twice and tried again both times.  Apparently, all three attempts succeeded.

It would be great if a mod could contact me or if anyone could point me at the right contact location.  My app isn't named here to prevent this from looking like advertising.

Comment: We're looking into it for you - we'll get a response from the team hopefully within a day or two. Don't worry, you're probably not going to get disqualified ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted two of them. Can't imagine that this would cause any harm, but if someone gives you crap about it later then you'll have this thread to point back to.

Comment: Great thanks.  Everything looks correct on my end.

Comment: Good job, Shog.

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up on this: There was a bug in which the creation of the App itself succeeded, but then the creation of the first revision in the App's history failed. When that happened, you received an error message, but the submission was successful (except for a weird revision history).

That bug has since been fixed, so this shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: Apparently [it happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157665/accidental-duplicate-app-submission-on-apptivate-ms).