# Accidental Duplicate App Submission on Apptivate.ms

Tags: support, status-completed, apptivate.ms

I accidentally submitted my app twice on Apptivate.ms

The first several times I submitted the app I received an error, so I tried again later and it went through. I didn't realize that one of the initial submissions must have worked, even though it errored on me. Can a moderator assist and remove one of the redundant listings, please? I apologize for the inconvenience. Thanks!

http://apptivate.ms/apps/1424/alpaca-childrens-story-books

http://apptivate.ms/apps/1426/alpaca-childrens-story-books

Comment: Related: [My app got submitted to the Apptivate.ms content multiple times because of an error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154757/my-app-got-submitted-to-the-apptivate-ms-content-multiple-times-because-of-an-er)

Comment: Do you by any chance recall what the error was about?

Comment: The errors I was getting were in IE 10, and indicated that the server was too busy to accept the request. I tried again a few hours later with Chrome and it worked fine, so I wasn't sure if it was an IE 10 issue or truly a server error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to explain what happened:

You submitted the app twice within less than a second (possibly you accidentally hit Enter while also clicking, or something like that). The first submission worked quite right; however, before your browser received the response to that, it sent the second submission, which then caused the throttler response (because you cannot submit two apps in such quick succession).

Thus while the first submission went through just fine, you just never knew.

And since BoltClock removed the dupe, all is a good again.

No need to apologize :)

Comment: `onclick="this.disabled=true;"`. Fixed. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That happens already (because double-click on the submit button is the *usual* reason for double-submission). But there are less likely ways to double-submit, and we didn't bother catching all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted #1426, the one that you posted later. Don't worry, you won't be disqualified (I should think not anyway). Good luck in the competition!